# enable -tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath for only specific cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Normally, when you define `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath`, you can switch all cells to editing mode by swiping.
But, I'd like to enable `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` for only specific cell.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another delegate method of table view

```
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
```

where you can define whether row can be edit or not for specific index path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Besides **Malav Soni** says,you can also do it in this delegate mehtod

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row !=  yourrow){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```